# Infinite hexagonal impedance network with loads at specific nodes

Tags: impedance, passive-networks

It's been a couple weeks already that I am trying to solve this network on the paper. It consists on a infinite/periodical hexagonal lattice but with some peculiarities. First of all, this is not the same network as the one asked [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/289211/hexagonal-resistor-circuit-equivalent-resistance)
My network can be seen in the attached figure. At each vertex of the hexagons, a load ZL is to be placed. Zs is unknown and I would like to calculate it in order to maximize the power transmission from point A to point B, for example.

[image: Hexagonal network]

It is obvious that the impedance seen from A is the parallel of the three branches. After the first impedance Zs at each branch, the impedance seen right afterwards will consist of the parallel of two branches and ZL. Since the network is infinite, I have considered that the impedance seen from each branch will always be the same.

Therefore, I would have a simple calculation.

1. First, I assume that all impedances are real.
2. If I want maximum power transfer to the network from point A as an input, the impedance seen from A should be equal to ZL (since the conjugate of a real number is the number itself). This gives us: Zin = Zbranch/3= ZL
3. The impedance seen from each branch would be the series of Zs + the parallel of ZL and two branches. Namely:

\$ Zbranch = Zs + ZL*Zbranch/(2*ZL + Zbranch)\$

After substituting the value of Zbranch that can be extracted from 2), I get a value of 12/5*ZL for Zs.

In my head it results so simple that I do not believe this result is correct. However, I cannot think of a more complex analysis.
Could you provide me with some feedback and maybe any more complex technique for analysing this network? Thank you

Comment: Looks like a carbon chain, of graphene..

Comment: I'm afraid it has nothing to do with graphene, It's more about circuits. The ZLs would be input/output ports.